# chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener() do not work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Making simple extension. But can't force to work this Event.

manifest File:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Extantion",
"version": "0.1",

"content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches": ["http://foo.bar/*"],
        "js": ["js/jq.js","js/injection.js"]
    }
]
```

};

contentScript File:

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
console.log("Hello World");
});
```

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (and perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done.

Comment: The documentation also links [sample extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:pageAction).

Comment: onClicked
Fired when a page action icon is clicked. This event **will not fire** if the page action has a popup.

manifest.json

   ` "page_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/icon_16.png"
    },`

on background page

 `chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(details){
    console.log(details);
})       `

**will not fire on content_script**

Comment: Don't forget to set a pageaction for the tab you want to call onClick
`chrome.pageAction.show(tabs.tabId, function(d){
        console.log(d);
    });`